# Mark a function deprecated in one specific file

Tags: php, phpstorm, deprecated

I have a sidemenuBuilder.php which has lines like this:

```
$exampleMenu->addChild('Example', ['route' => 'admin_example_index']);
```

The addChild is from the vendor dir, so I can not make any changes to it. I have made a new function in the sidemenuBuilder, called `securedAddChild`, which implements some security checks.

I would like to mark `addChild` as deprecated (or another way for a strike-through) **for this file only**, with the message to use the `securedAddChild` instead, in order to motivate others to use the proper function.

Can I create a (fairly simple) way to mark `addChild` strike-through?

---

*Edit: The interface method per suggested in the comments works sortof. Various returntypes will start giving messages that they're incorrect. It's not as "drop in" as I'd prefer.*

Comment: I think this is where documentations are for.

Comment: Isn't `/**\n* @deprecated \n*/` above the addChild method sufficient?

Comment: I somewhat agree, but documentation should be read, but it hardly does :)

Comment: @Tom: No, it's in the vendor dir, I can not make changes to it.

Comment: Extend the vendor class and throw an decrepated Exception to prevent using it.

Comment: well then I'd suggest writing an extending class for the vendor dir instead of using it directly

Comment: @Tom That probably still won't prevent developers from using the original class if they don't happen to notice the extended version.

Comment: I could make an `ItemInterface` that extends their `ItemInterface` and mark that deprecated

Comment: Try this: copy the whole original file into some folder (will be used by IDE only; e.g. `.ide-helpers` or whatever); do your modifications there (add that `@deprecated` tag). See how it will behave -- IDE should now report "Multiple definitions exist for class XXX" warning (you may disable that inspection if desired). It may not style it as deprecated in the actual code (because of multiple classes)... but in code completion popup it will show such method with strike through. See what place is more important for you: completion popup or actual usage place.